# Como Insertar una Categoria y un Articulo si ambos no existen en un Procedimiento Almacenado?

Tags: sql-server

Buenas estoy intentando registrar un articulo
y mi problema surge cuando intento registrar un articulo que no existe en la tabla Articulos
y a su vez cuando **idCategoria** no existe en la tabla **Categoria**.

Cuando ejecuto el procedimiento almacenado crea mi categoria si no existe, pero en
*INSERT INTO Articulos(CodigoArticulo,Nombre,Descripcion,**IdCategoria**)* debido a que aun no existe me da error
noce si hay alguna forma de esperar algo asi como un await.

Ya que solo cumple el registrar el articulo y la Categoria
si ejecuto 2 veces el procedimiento almacenado , lo cual a mi entender
esta registrando la categoria ya que la crea y luego termina el sp

```
 (
 @Id INT,
 @Ruc varchar(11),
 @CodigoArticulo varchar(40),
 @Nombre varchar(50),
 @Descripcion varchar (250),
 @Categoria varchar (40),
 @Precio decimal (18,2),
 @Cantidad decimal (18,2),
 @Unidad varchar (15)
 )  
AS  
begin  
DECLARE @IdCategoria INTEGER
DECLARE @IdArticulo INTEGER
DECLARE @VALIDAR INTEGER

SET @VALIDAR =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articulos WHERE CodigoArticulo = @CodigoArticulo)

SET @IdCategoria = dbo.usp_registrar_categoria(@Categoria)
IF(@IdCategoria = 0)

INSERT INTO Categoria(Nombre)VALUES (@categoria)
SELECT @IdArticulo as IdArticulo, @IdCategoria as IdCategoria

IF(@VALIDAR = 0)
INSERT INTO Articulos(CodigoArticulo,Nombre,Descripcion,IdCategoria)
VALUES(@CodigoArticulo,@Nombre,@Descripcion,@IdCategoria)

EXEC usp_Guardar_Articulo 
0,'123456789','CodeTest001','CodeTest','CodeTest','Televisores',100,50,'Unidad'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, semánticamente hay diferencias entre un procedimiento almacenado y una función, lo que necesitas es una función para la categoría ya que te debe retornar un valor, te dejo un aproximado de cómo debería ser (hace tiempo no uso SQL, probablemente hayan fallas de sintaxis):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnc_registrar_categoria(@name varchar)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @IdCategoria INTEGER
  SELECT @IdCategoria as IdCategoria FROM Categoria WHERE Nombre=@name
  IF @IdCategoria IS NULL
    INSERT INTO Categoria (Nombre) VALUES (@name)
    SELECT @IdCategoria as SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  END
  RETURN @IdCategoria
END
```

Y el procedimiento almacenado quedaría:

```
-- ...
AS  
begin  
DECLARE @IdCategoria INTEGER
DECLARE @IdArticulo INTEGER
DECLARE @VALIDAR INTEGER

SET @VALIDAR =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articulos WHERE CodigoArticulo = @CodigoArticulo)

SET @IdCategoria = dbo.usp_registrar_categoria(@Categoria)
-- HACER EL RESTO

EXEC usp_Guardar_Articulo 
0,'123456789','CodeTest001','CodeTest','CodeTest','Televisores',100,50,'Unidad'
```

Eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias @Ty Viera ya tenia la funcion creada, exeptuando el uso de el Scope_Identity()